# Simple Applicative Functor Example

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

I'm reading the Learn You a Haskell book. I'm struggling to understand this applicative functor code:

```
(*) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) $ 2
```

This boils down to: (3+2) * (2*2) = 20

I don't follow how. I can expand the above into the less elegant but more explicit for newbie comprehension version:

```
((fmap (*) (+3)) <*> (*2)) 2
```

I understand the basics of the `<*>` operator. This makes perfect sense:

```
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But I don't see how the command works? Any tips?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One method to approach this types of questions is to use substitution. Take the operator, in this case `(<*>)` or function, get its implementation and insert it to the code in question.

In the case of `(*) <$> (+3) <*> (*2) $ 2` you are using the `((->) a)` instance of `Applicative` found in [the `Applicative` module in base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Control-Applicative.html#Applicative), you can find the instance by clicking the source link on the right and searching for "(->":

```
instance Applicative ((->) a) where
    pure = const
    (<*>) f g x = f x (g x)
```

Using the definition for `(<*>)` we can continue substituting:

```
((fmap (*) (+3)) <*> (*2)) 2 == (fmap (*) (+3)) 2 ((*2) 2)
== (fmap (*) (+3)) 2 4
```

Ok now we need the Functor instance for `((->) a)`.  You can find this by going to the haddock info for `Functor`, [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t%3aFunctor) clicking on the source link on the right and searching for "(->" to find:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

Now continuing substituting:

```
(fmap (*) (+3)) 2 4 == ((*) . (+3)) 2 4
== (*) ((+3) 2) 4
== (*) 5 4
== 20
```

#### A more symbolic appraoch

Many people report better long term sucess with these types of problems when thinking about them symbolically.  Instead of feeding the 2 value through the problem lets focus instead on `(*) <$> (+3) <*> (*2)` and only apply the 2 at the end.

```
(*) <$> (+3) <*> (*2)
== ((*) . (+3)) <*> (*2)
== (\x -> ((*) . (+3)) x ((*2) x))
== (\x -> ((*) . (+3)) x (x * 2))
== (\x -> (*) (x + 3) (x * 2))
== (\x -> (x + 3) * (x * 2))
== (\x -> 2 * x * x + 6 * x)
```

Ok now plug in 2 for x

```
2 * 2 * 2 + 6 * 2
8 + 12
20
```

Comment: wow, pretty awesome answer. way better than the text book. thanks!

Comment: Really awesome, made me think through the process. One minor thing though: while trying in GHCI the symbolic approach, it gave errors if I didn't put the function application operator (`$`) in the third line, before `(*2)`.

Comment: @rubik - yeah you are right, I am going add parens so it matches what I have for '<*>'